# Serializing a List of objects containing a List of objects in Android

Tags: java, android, list, serialization, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList`-`List<Checklist> checklists`. The class `Checklist` contains an `ArrayList`-`List<Item> items`. These store a series of checklists and their items for users of my app. Is it possible to serialize the list `checklists` in order to save the users checklists?

I've tried everything I could find and the best I could do is serialize `checklists` without the `items` field into an array of bytes.

If this is impossible, should I restructure my lists or is there a better way to save this data? (DB perhaps)

Answer (score 0):

I have serialized objects using the GSON library as JSON strings and deserialized them. Results were great.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

The library is smart enough to recognize similarly named variables and type them appropriately. I highly recommend this approach. It will even recognize if you have classes within classes. Its great.